# Return the average number for the section in the open file python

Tags: python, file, list, readline

i am given a a text file with 8 lines, and on each line there is an IDnumber, name, section and grade seperated by whitespace.  im supposed to return the average for the given section.  i am brand new to python therefore am having a horrible time trying to figure it out. can someone please help?
my parameters are a random textfile, and a section number

def average_by_secion (textfile, section):

```
'''(io.TextIOWrapper, str) -> flt or NoneType
```

Comment: average what for the given section? grade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting some general process:

1. read every line of file and check if the section matches the section you need.
   there are lots of [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) on how to read a file in python.  [Csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module could help you turn your lines into either lists or dictionaries
2. if the line has a matching section number you could add its grade to a collection [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) `section_grades_list = []`
3. once you have a list of grades to average it should be pretty easy from there `sum(section_grades_list) / len(section_grades_list)`

Answer (score 2):

```
listOfLines = []
while file:
   listOfLines.append(file.readline())
   total = 0
   numOfGrades = 0
   for i in listOfLines:
       total+=int(i.split()[3])
   numOfGrades += 1

return total/numOfGrades
```

I think...